3-legged OAuth フローを使用したトークンの取得がうまくいかない
実現したいこと
OAuth1.0の認証をライブラリを使用せずに実行したい

経緯
Xの広告費を取得するコードをphpで書いている
しかしphpの環境が古くversionや依存関係からライブラリを使用できない
そのため自力でOAuthの認証をしないと行けないという状況

発生している問題・分からないこと
3-legged OAuth フローを使用したフローでOAuthの認証をしようとしている
ステップ2でリダイレクトに失敗している。
ここを解決したい

ステップ 1: POST oauth/request_token
取得に成功
oauth_token
oauth_token_secret
oauth_callback_confirmed

ステップ 2: GET oauth/authorize
ここで失敗


取得できない
oauth_token
oauth_verifier


キャプ




URLがエラーを吐いている
https://api.twitter.com/login/error?username_or_email=%40AccountName&redirect_after_login=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Foauth_token%3DqyuthgAAAAABs_7wAAABj2Ddie0


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
